# Microphone Access Prompt Not Being Presented

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

In my audio recording application I'm trying to ask the user for access to the microphone. However, I keep getting the .NotDetermined case and no prompt. The documentation states that the Not Determined case will prompt the user but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
@IBAction func recordTapped(recordButton: UIButton!){

    let microPhoneStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

    switch microPhoneStatus {
    case .Authorized:
        // Has access
        println("access")
        vibrate()

        recordNow()

    case .Denied:
        // No access granted
        println("denied")


    case .Restricted:
        // Microphone disabled in settings
        println("mic disabled in settings")


    case .NotDetermined:
        // Didn't request access yet
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, completionHandler: nil)
        println("Not determined")
    }



}
```